# How to Repopulate Django ChoiceField Out-of-Band If Another ChoiceField Changes?

Tags: jquery, ajax, django, django-models, django-forms

I have a Django form that displays the country and state/province/region that the user lives in.  In this form, I display all the countries in a form ChoiceField called 'country' using a Select widget that I pre-populate from a list.  If the user lives in either the United States or Canada, I'll create another form ChoiceField called 'region' that also uses a Select widget and which I pre-populate using either a list of US states or Canadian provinces.  The form label for either of these fields is "State" or "Province" respectively.  If the user is from any other country, I represent the region field as a CharField using a TextInput widget and I allow them to optionally enter a region name in this field.  Its label is "State/Province/Region".  When the user first comes to this page, I know the country they're in so I prepopulate the country and region fields appropriately.  Here are my requirements but I'm not sure how to implement them in Django.

1. If the user is in the US and changes the country pulldown to Canada, I'd like to go "out-of-band" back to the server, fetch the list of Canada's regions, and repopulate the region pulldown with those regions.  I'd also like to change the label from "State" to "Province".  I don't want to have to refresh the page.
2. If the user in Canada and switches to the US, I'll do the same thing but in reverse.
3. If the user is in the US or Canada and changes the county to any other country, I'd just like to change the form control from a ChoiceField to a CharField without having to do a page refresh.
4. If the user is in any country other than the US or Canada and selects either of those two countries, I'd like to do the reverse and change the region from a CharField to a ChoiceField, again without a page refresh.
5. Finally, I'd like the technique to be scalable, meaning that it wouldn't be too difficult to modify the code when I start tracking the regions of another country such as Mexico.

Here are my files:

```
# models.py
class Profile(models.Model):
    region = models.CharField(max_length=30, null=True, blank=True)
    country = models.ForeignKey('Country')

# forms.py
class BusinessProfileForm(forms.Form):
    country = forms.ChoiceField(
        choices = COUNTRIES,
        widget = forms.Select())

class USBusinessProfileForm(BusinessProfileForm):
    region = forms.ChoiceField(
        choices = US_STATES,
        widget = forms.Select())

class CABusinessProfileForm(BusinessProfileForm):
    region = forms.ChoiceField(
        choices = CA_PROVINCES,
        widget = forms.Select())

class OtherBusinessProfileForm(BusinessProfileForm):
    region = forms.CharField(
        required = False,
        widget = forms.TextInput())

# choices.py
COUNTRIES = [
    ('US', _('United States')),
    ('GB', _('United Kingdom')),
    ('CA', _('Canada')),
    ...]
US_STATES = [
    ('AL', _('Alabama')),
    ('AK', _('Alaska')),
    ...]
CA_PROVINCES = [
    ('AB', _('Alberta')),
    ('BC', _('British Columbia')),
    ...]
```

Can anyone help me understand how to solve this problem in Django?  I'm not sure how to wrap my head around it.  It seems pretty complicated.  Just thinking out loud, it seems like I would have to assign some sort of click event to the country control.  When it fires, I read the new country selected, and if it's one of the countries who's regions I track, make an out-of-band request back to some "thing" on the server which will return the appropriate list.  I would then repopulate the control with the list and change the control's label.  If the country isn't one whose regions I track, I recreate the control as a CharField and change the label.  If the user switches from one country I don't track to another I don't track (e.g. from Mexico to Costa Rica), I do nothing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You won't solve this problem in pure Django, as Django is a server application and some client code is needed to achieve what you want.

Fortunately, your goal is rather common, so there are plenty of tutorials out there showing how to do what you want. [Here is an example](http://phppot.com/jquery/jquery-dependent-dropdown-list-countries-and-states/) (ignore the PHP part). In case you don't know anything about client libs/frameworks like jQuery, AngularJS etc, or even about Javascript itself, that's a good way to get you started.